# Using Angular Material matMenu as context menu

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have been trying to sort out how to use a matMenu as context menu triggered when somebody right clicks on one of my elements.

This is my menu:

```
<mat-menu #contextMenu="matMenu">
   <button mat-menu-item>
      <mat-icon>table_rows</mat-icon>
      <span>Select Whole Row</span>
      <span>⌘→</span>
   </button>
   <button mat-menu-item>
      <mat-icon>functions</mat-icon>
      <span>Insert Subtotal</span>
      <span>⌃S</span>
   </button>
</mat-menu>
```

I want to be able to trigger the menu when this element is right-clicked:

```
<div tabindex=0 *ngIf="!hasRowFocus" 
                class="display-cell" (keydown)="onSelectKeyDown($event)" 
                (click)=selectCellClick($event) 
                (dblclick)=selectCellDblClick($event)
                (contextmenu)="openContextMenu()"
                [ngClass]='selectClass'
                (mouseover)="mouseover()"
                (mouseout)="mouseout()"
           
                #cellSelect >
     <div (dragenter) = "mouseDragEnter($event)" (dragleave) = "mouseDragLeave($event)">{{templateDisplayValue}}</div>
</div>
```

However, according to the documentation, I need to specify this div should have the `[matMenuTriggerFor]` directive, so that so when `openContextMenu()` it triggered by right clicking, I can call get a reference to the trigger element and then call `triggerElement.trigger()` to spawn the menu.

Problem is it appears that setting `[matMenuTriggerFor]` is hooked up to the click event automatically, not the right click event, so anytime I **left** click on the element the context menu opens, which is not the desired behavor.

I have seen workarounds like this one on [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-context-menu?file=app%2Fcontext-menu-example.ts) which creates a hidden div as the trigger element, but requires supplying x & y coordinates for the location of the menu element which seems suboptimal.

Any way to have the menu triggered by right clicking on the input element without having to create a dummy element to host the matMenuTriggerFor directive?

Comment: extend MatMenuTrigger and override decorators?

Answer (score 10):

Luckily the code to `matMenuTriggerFor` is posted here:
https://github.com/angular/components/blob/master/src/material/menu/menu-trigger.ts

If you look at the bottom of file at the `MatMenuTrigger` class, it is straightforward to override the same base class, do a few tricks, and roll our own `matContextMenuTriggerFor` directive:

```js
import { Directive, HostListener, Input } from "@angular/core";
import { MatMenuPanel, _MatMenuTriggerBase } from "@angular/material/menu";
import { fromEvent, merge } from "rxjs";

// @Directive declaration styled same as matMenuTriggerFor
// with different selector and exportAs.
@Directive({
  selector: `[matContextMenuTriggerFor]`,
  host: {
    'class': 'mat-menu-trigger',
  },
  exportAs: 'matContextMenuTrigger',
})
export class MatContextMenuTrigger extends _MatMenuTriggerBase {

  // Duplicate the code for the matMenuTriggerFor binding
  // using a new property and the public menu accessors.
  @Input('matContextMenuTriggerFor')
  get menu_again() {
    return this.menu;
  }
  set menu_again(menu: MatMenuPanel) {
    this.menu = menu;
  }

  // Make sure to ignore the original binding
  // to allow separate menus on each button.
  @Input('matMenuTriggerFor')
  set ignoredMenu(value: any) { }

  // Override _handleMousedown, and call super._handleMousedown 
  // with a new MouseEvent having button numbers 2 and 0 reversed.
  _handleMousedown(event: MouseEvent): void {
    return super._handleMousedown(new MouseEvent(event.type, Object.assign({}, event, { button: event.button === 0 ? 2 : event.button === 2 ? 0 : event.button })));
  }

  // Override _handleClick to make existing binding to clicks do nothing.
  _handleClick(event: MouseEvent): void { }

  // Create a place to store the host element.
  private hostElement: EventTarget | null = null;

  // Listen for contextmenu events (right-clicks), then:
  //  1) Store the hostElement for use in later events.
  //  2) Prevent browser default action.
  //  3) Call super._handleClick to open the menu as expected.
  @HostListener('contextmenu', ['$event'])
  _handleContextMenu(event: MouseEvent): void {
    this.hostElement = event.target;
    if (event.shiftKey) return; // Hold a shift key to open original context menu. Delete this line if not desired behavior.
    event.preventDefault();
    super._handleClick(event);
  }

  // The complex logic below is to handle submenus and hasBackdrop===false well.
  // Listen for click and contextmenu (right-click) events on entire document.
  // If this menu is open, one of the following conditional actions.
  //   1) If the click came from the overlay backdrop, close the menu and prevent default.
  //   2) If the click came inside the overlay container, it was on a menu. If it was
  //      a contextmenu event, prevent default and re-dispatch it as a click.
  //   3) If the event did not come from our host element, close the menu.
  private contextListenerSub = merge(
    fromEvent(document, "contextmenu"),
    fromEvent(document, "click"),
  ).subscribe(event => {
    if (this.menuOpen) {
      if (event.target) {
        const target = event.target as HTMLElement;
        if (target.classList.contains("cdk-overlay-backdrop")) {
          event.preventDefault();
          this.closeMenu();
        } else {
          let inOverlay = false;
          document.querySelectorAll(".cdk-overlay-container").forEach(e => {
            if (e.contains(target))
              inOverlay = true;
          });
          if (inOverlay) {
            if (event.type === "contextmenu") {
              event.preventDefault();
              event.target?.dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent("click", event));
            }
          } else
            if (target !== this.hostElement)
              this.closeMenu();
        }
      }
    }
  });

  // When destroyed, stop listening for the contextmenu events above, 
  // null the host element reference, then call super.
  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.contextListenerSub.unsubscribe();
    this.hostElement = null;
    return super.ngOnDestroy();
  }
}
```

Add the `MatContextMenuTrigger` directive to the `declarations` list in your module file, then it is just like using the normal one:

```html
<div [matContextMenuTriggerFor]="myContextMenu">
  Right click here to open context menu.
</div>
<mat-menu #myContextMenu="matMenu">
  My context menu.
</mat-menu>
```

And you can have separate menus for both left-click and right-click:

```html
<div [matMenuTriggerFor]="myNormalMenu" [matContextMenuTriggerFor]="myContextMenu">
  Left click here to open normal menu.<br>
  Right click here to open context menu.
</div>
<mat-menu #myNormalMenu="matMenu">
  My normal menu.
</mat-menu>
<mat-menu #myContextMenu="matMenu">
  My context menu.
</mat-menu>
```

Comment: This works for me. But all material menus on my site starts to lag and delay after adding this, also my normal material menus (not context) gets this problem.

Comment: I finally got enough reputation to say thanks for this solution!  I'm using it and I wish it was part of the core Angular Material!  fwiw, like @Danie observed, I noticed that I get severe performance issues waiting for the menu when I have a lot of these on a page (say in a table with a hundred rows and a dozen columns, each cell having their own context menu.  It might be there for a regular menu too as I have not verified.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you can use css `pointer-events: none;` and wrap `[matMenuTriggerFor]="contextMenu"` inside the list like this

```html
<p>Right-click on the items below to show the context menu:</p>
<mat-list>
    <mat-list-item *ngFor="let item of items" (contextmenu)="onContextMenu($event, item)">
    <div [matMenuTriggerFor]="contextMenu" style="pointer-events: none;">{{ item.name }}</div>
    </mat-list-item>
</mat-list>
<mat-menu #contextMenu="matMenu">
    <ng-template matMenuContent let-item="item">
        <button mat-menu-item (click)="onContextMenuAction1(item)">Action 1</button>
        <button mat-menu-item (click)="onContextMenuAction2(item)">Action 2</button>
    </ng-template>
</mat-menu>
```

Here is the [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-context-menu-tu26u1?file=app/context-menu-example.html)

But it is not preferable. I think you should use the [overlay](https://material.angular.io/cdk/overlay/overview) replace with menu

Comment: Thanks, this is helpful, but I can't disable my pointer events because (click) and (hover) and some other events are also triggers in my app on the element which for whicih I need this context menu.  However I was able to adapt your solution for the purpose by adding a dummy element, which programatically clicks the trigger when the context menu is clicked.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the solution I found. Context menu will open on cursor position.

Create a component named to `ContextMenuComponent`

```
    import { Component, HostBinding } from '@angular/core';
import { MatMenuTrigger } from '@angular/material/menu';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-context-menu',
  template: '<ng-content></ng-content>',
  styles: ['']
})
export class ContextMenuComponent extends MatMenuTrigger {

  @HostBinding('style.position') private position = 'fixed';
  @HostBinding('style.pointer-events') private events = 'none';
  @HostBinding('style.left') private x: string;
  @HostBinding('style.top') private y: string;

  // Intercepts the global context menu event
  public open({ x, y }: MouseEvent, data?: any) {

    // Pass along the context data to support lazily-rendered content
    if(!!data) { this.menuData = data; }

    // Adjust the menu anchor position
    this.x = x + 'px';
    this.y = y + 'px';

    // Opens the menu
    this.openMenu();
    
    // prevents default
    return false;
  }
}
```

Use context menu as bellow on where you want

```
<app-context-menu [matMenuTriggerFor]="main" #menu>
        
    <mat-menu #main="matMenu">
    
        <ng-template matMenuContent let-name="name">
    
          <button mat-menu-item>{{ name }}</button>
          <button mat-menu-item>Menu item 1</button>
          <button mat-menu-item>Menu item 2</button>
    
          <button mat-menu-item [matMenuTriggerFor]="sub">
            Others...
          </button>
    
        </ng-template>
    
      </mat-menu>
    
      <mat-menu #sub="matMenu">
        <button mat-menu-item>Menu item 3</button>
        <button mat-menu-item>Menu item 4</button>
      </mat-menu>
        
        </app-context-menu>
    
    <section fxLayout="column" fxLayoutAlign="center center" (contextmenu)="menu.open($event, { name: 'Stack Overflow'} )">
    
      <p>Try to right click and see how it works!</p>
      <p>You do whatever you want here...</p>
    
    </section>
```

Answer (score 1):

For anyone else looking, this was the easiest setup.  Follows mostly how [MatMenuTrigger](https://github.com/angular/components/blob/main/src/material/menu/menu-trigger.ts) works just handles on (contextmenu) rather than (click).

```
import { Directive, HostBinding, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { MatMenuPanel, MatMenuTrigger } from '@angular/material/menu';


@Directive({
    selector: '[matMenuTriggerForContext]',
    host: {
        'class': 'mat-mdc-menu-trigger',
        '[attr.aria-haspopup]': 'menu ? "menu" : null',
        '[attr.aria-expanded]': 'menuOpen',
        '[attr.aria-controls]': 'menuOpen ? menu.panelId : null',
        '(contextmenu)': '_handleContextMenu($event)',
      },
      exportAs: 'matMenuTriggerContext'
})
export class MatMenuTriggerForContextDirective extends MatMenuTrigger {
    @Input('matMenuTriggerForContext')
    get _matMenuTriggerForContext(): MatMenuPanel | null {
        return this.menu;
      }
    set _matMenuTriggerForContext(v: MatMenuPanel | null) {
        this.menu = v;
    }

    _handleContextMenu($event: MouseEvent): boolean {
        $event?.stopPropagation();
        $event?.preventDefault();
        $event?.stopImmediatePropagation();
        this._handleClick($event);
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't seem like its possible to disconnect the `(click)` from triggering `MatMenuTrigger` short of disabling mouse events entirely, U can't do that in my app because the same element which needs a context menu also needs to respond to click hover and drag events.  But the dummy element approach can be simplified and doesn't require seem to require providing positional information as in the following example, adapted from ttQuants stackblitz example in his useful answer.

```
export class ContextMenuExample {
  items = [
    { id: 1, name: "Item 1" },
    { id: 2, name: "Item 2" },
    { id: 3, name: "Item 3" }
  ];
  @ViewChildren(MatMenuTrigger)
  contextMenuTriggers: QueryList<MatMenuTrigger>;
  
  onContextMenu(event: MouseEvent, item: Item, idx : number) { 
    event.preventDefault();
    this.contextMenuTriggers.toArray()[idx].openMenu();  
  }

  onContextMenuAction1(item: Item) {
    alert(`Click on Action 1 for ${item.name}`);
  }

  onContextMenuAction2(item: Item) {
    alert(`Click on Action 2 for ${item.name}`);
  } 
}

export interface Item {
  id: number;
  name: string;
}
```

Template:

```
<p>Right-click on the items below to show the context menu:</p>
<mat-list>
    <mat-list-item *ngFor="let item of items; let idx=index">
       <div (contextmenu)="onContextMenu($event, item, idx)">{{item.name}}
          <div [matMenuTriggerFor]="contextMenu" style="visibility: hidden; 
             pointer-events: none;">{{ item.name }}
          </div>
       </div>
    </mat-list-item>
</mat-list>
<mat-menu #contextMenu="matMenu">
    <ng-template matMenuContent let-item="item">
        <button mat-menu-item (click)="onContextMenuAction1(item)">Action 1</button>
        <button mat-menu-item (click)="onContextMenuAction2(item)">Action 2</button>
    </ng-template>
</mat-menu>
```

Comment: This does not work. It doesn't close the menu if you right click somewhere else...